# GoogleMapsAPI - change strokeColor of polygon after initialization

Tags: javascript, google-maps-api-3, google-visualization

I am creating a web application that uses GoogleMapsAPI to render multiple polygons on the Google Maps.

```
var polyCoords = [];

function initMap(){
   var loc = {lat:23, lng:90};
   var polyArr = [{coords : coordsof P1, weight: weight of P1}, ..... , {coords of Pn}];
   map = new google.maps.Map(
                 document.getElementById('map'), {
                    zoom : 11,
                    center : loc
                });
   for (var poly in polyArr){
       var gridPoly = new google.maps.Polygon({
                                paths : polyArr[poly].coords,
                                strokeColor : "#FF0000",
                                strokeOpacity : 0.8,
                                strokeWeight : 2,
                                fillColor : "#FF0000",
                                fillOpacity : 0.10
                            });
       gridPoly.setMap(map);
       polyCoords[grid] = gridPoly; // polyCoords.push(gridPoly);
   }
}
```

The above code visualizes the maps correctly. But, I have a HTML slider that gives me a value that I use to filter to based on the weight value in the `polyArr` variable. Now I want to change the `strokeColor` of the filtered out polygons.

```
function updateStroke(filterIndex){
    polyCoors[filterIndex].strokeColor = '#000000';
    polyCoors[filterIndex].setMap(map);
}
```

This doesn't appear to work.

Comment: Does polyCoors carry the coordinats or the polygon instance itself. There are lots of arrays in the code I could not understand which one is which

Comment: I forgot to add the line `polyCoords[poly] = gridPoly` in the question

Comment: What is not working setMap method?

Comment: If you see the `updateStroke()`, there I am updating the color of the border of the polygon to black. It is not reflected on the map.

Comment: I get a javascript error with the posted code: `Uncaught ReferenceError: polyCoords is not defined`

Comment: I don't believe that should be the case.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try the following:

```
polyCoors[filterIndex].setOptions({strokeColor: '#000000'})
```

For more info visit the PolygonOptions documentation https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/reference#PolygonOptions
Hope that works!

Comment: Thanks, this is such a un-intuitive implementation on Google's part.